# ASP EF Core between query 'greater than or equal' throwing compile error?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a query in ASP Razor EF Core which runs ok:

```
Model.Bookings.Where(x => x.DateOfVisit > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1) && x.DateOfVisit < DateTime.Now).Count() > 10
```

I have realised that I need the query to be 'greater than or equal to' and 'less than or equal to' but when I change the code to this:

```
Model.Bookings.Where(x => x.DateOfVisit >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1) && x.DateOfVisit =< DateTime.Now).Count() > 10
```

I get 2 errors - one for **invald expression term '<'** and the other for **Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'DateTime**

I've done these types of queries in SQL many times but I can't see why it won't let me use this logic/format.  I've been Googling for over an hour but I can't see why it wont work - please will somone put me out of my misery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the second '=' wrong, it's after the '<'

```
Model.Bookings.Where(x => x.DateOfVisit >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1) && x.DateOfVisit <= DateTime.Now).Count() > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
   DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
   DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now;
   Model.Bookings.Where(x => x.DateOfVisit >= d1  && x.DateOfVisit <= d2 ).Count() > 10
```